# how to access foreign table field in django view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have two models, the plans model & plans features ( foreign relation with plans table), given below:
[image: models.py]

Following is the view which returns an object of features for each plan:
[image: view.py]

Now I want to access, the "price" field of the plans table (model). How this is possible?
my Django template is the following which doesn't work:
[image: template code]

I belive there is solution to this, I would love hear from you . thank you

Comment: please share code instead of screenshots

Comment: in your foor loop `<li> {{each_feature.plan.price}} </li>` is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you use **filter** returns a queryset, not a single object so you can not direct access the foreign key with **dot**

**Solution:**

1. Use **.get()**
2. Use **.filter().first()**

You can choose from above two.

Assuming you have unique entries for basic, standard and professional packages

### Option 1

```py
basic = plans_features.objects.filter(plan__title="BASIC")
standard = plans_features.objects.filter(plan__title="STANDARD")
professional = plans_features.objects.filter(plan__title="PROFESSIONAL")

context = {
    "basic": basic,
    "standard": standard,
    "professional": professional
}
```

```
<ul class="deal-item">
{% for package in basic %}
    <li>{{ package.plan.price }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
<ul class="deal-item">
{% for package in standard %}
    <li>{{ package.plan.price }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
<ul class="deal-item">
{% for package in professional %}
    <li>{{ package.plan.price }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

### Option 2

If you only want to print prices once for every package,

```py
basic = plans_features.objects.filter(plan__title="BASIC").first()
standard = plans_features.objects.filter(plan__title="STANDARD").first()
professional = plans_features.objects.filter(plan__title="PROFESSIONAL").first()

context = {
    "basic": basic,
    "standard": standard,
    "professional": professional
}
```

```
<ul class="deal-item">
    <li>{{ basic.plan.price }}</li>
</ul>
<ul class="deal-item">
    <li>{{ standard.plan.price }}</li>
</ul>
<ul class="deal-item">
    <li>{{ professional.plan.price }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Asim, thanks for answering, but it gives an error "MultipleObjectsReturned" "get() returned more than one plans_features -- it returned 2!" because it not only returns a single price value but also feature_title of plans table.  that could me more than one feature.

Comment: isntead of get it should be filter

Comment: @Shahhussain See the answer, I've updated it according to multiple objects returned.

Comment: @AsimEjaz thanks for the way you are helping! 

let's say there are two features for the basic plan, so it will iterate through two times, and this way it will print "<li>{{ package.plan.price }}</li>" two times. did you get my point?

otherwise, it works through iteration.

Comment: @Shahhussain Yes, if your package has 2 features, option 1 will print it 2 times. For printing price once for every package, follow option 2.